# Difference height between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

sorry for my English..

hi, I have a window it up with a jQuery code, that problem is the window to come on Chrome it is 1.5cm bigger as in Firefox.

My Firefox Version **68.6.0esr**

My Chrome Version **80.0.3987.149**

My Html Code,

```
       <!-- call jQuery code -->
                   <div id="layerPreview-3" > </div>
                   <div id='layerPreviewContent-3'>
                       <!-- jQuery code -->
                      <div id="tittel-text">Erfogreich zum Warenkorb hinzugefügt <span id="closse-text"  onclick="layer_close_3(event);">Schließen</span></div>

                        <div class="text-pruduct">

        <div class="bild-text">
            <img class="image-window" alt="" src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" />
            <div class="bild-text-anbieten">
                <p>Rucksack aus Hanf Gelbe</p>
                <p>Stückzahl: <b>1</b></p>
                <p>Bruttopreis: <b>40 &euro; </b></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="verticalLine"></div> 


        <div class="float_text">
            <p>Anzahl der Artikel im Waremkorb: 1 </p>
            <p>Wert des Warenkorbs: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ajax-product-block">
            <a class="button_weiter_einkaufen" href="lalo.php">weiter kaufen</a>
            <a class="button_zum_warenkorbs" href="lalo.php">zum warenkorb</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css code,

```
#layerPreview-3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
#layerPreviewContent-3 {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  background-color: #dedee0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 46%;
  margin-left: -350px;
  height: 20rem;

  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
 }
 .text-pruduct {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .bild-text {
    display: flex;
    width: 60%;
 }
 .bild-text img {
   max-width: 200px;
   margin: 1px;
 }
 .bild-text-anbieten {
    padding: 5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
 }
 .verticalLine {
     border-left: 2px solid #cccccc;
     height: 60%;
     position: absolute;
     left: 60%;
     margin-left: -3px;
     top: 18%;
}
.float_text{
   width: 40%;
   margin-top: 3%;
}
.float_text p{
  margin-left: 13%;
}
.bild-text .image-window{
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
}
.ajax-product-block {

   width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 30px;

}
.ajax-product-block a{
  padding: 0.3125rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ajax-product-block a{
 -webkit-padding-start: 0.3125rem;
}
.ajax-product-block  { margin-top: 8%; }

.button_weiter_einkaufen {

  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.35em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1.35;
  color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  color: black;

}
.button_weiter_einkaufen:hover {background-color: #666666;  color: white;}
.button_zum_warenkorbs { 
  display: inline-block;
  float: right; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.35em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1.35;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
 }
 .button_zum_warenkorbs:hover { background-color: #8c8c8c; color: white; }
```

How to show on Firefox

[image: how to show on firefox]

how to show on Chrome

[image: how to show on chrome]

can please someone explain me where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you verify that neither browser is zoomed in or out?

Comment: thanks for you answer sorry i don' t Understand what you means

Comment: @jennyfofenny is talking about [this](https://support.mozilla.org/de/kb/webseitenzoom) and [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=de). Check these.

Comment: In Firefox and Chrome, under the menu in the top right of the screen (stacked lines for Firefox and stacked dots for Chrome), you should see "Zoom" and you can check if it is set to something besides 100%.

Comment: On Chrome and firefox have 100% the zoom

Comment: Current Firefox is version 76.

Comment: I am with Linux Debian, and it updates the Browser a Little later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> #layerPreviewContent-3 {
>     ... 
>     height: 20rem;
>     ...
>    }
> ```

Your code above sets the height of the popup window to "20" [Root EM](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/); but your CSS does not *set* the Root EM.

You need to set a `html { ... }` font size value (which becomes the `Root EM`), otherwise it uses the *browser default value*, which may be different for each browser.

Therefore, add:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

To the top of your CSS and this will make the derived height value (20rem) the same across all browsers.

---

Ihr obiger Code setzt die Höhe des Popup-Fensters auf "20" Root EM; aber Ihr CSS setzt das Root EM nicht.

Sie müssen ein `html` setzen Wert für die Schriftgröße setzen (der zum Root-EM wird), andernfalls wird der Standardwert des Browsers verwendet, der für jeden Browser unterschiedlich sein kann.

Fügen Sie daher hinzu:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

an den Anfang Ihres CSS, wodurch der abgeleitete Höhenwert (20rem) in allen Browsern gleich ist.

Comment: Danke but not working..., I have on my Css File this to write ` html { font-size: 16px;}` also ` body { margin: 0;  padding: 0;  box-sizing: border-box;} `

Comment: @jdgs56z well you need to add this to your CSS in your question as it is not there.

Comment: @jdgs56z question: is your issue the outer box size or the box contents position?

Comment: it is the outer box size

Comment: @jdgs56z ok, thanks,. Are you able to [**inspect element** on Firefox](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Inspect-Element-in-Mozilla-Firefox), are you familiar with this toolset? This will help you find out what's what.

Comment: I am a little familiar...you think with a Firefox version 76 I to show different?

Comment: @ Martin I download last Firefox https://i.imgur.com/guq2o66.png and now it to show as Chrome, you have right.. my problem was my old firefox...ich wünsche dir ein schöne Tag!

Comment: Glad you solved it! Ich freue mich, dass Sie das Problem gelöst haben!